# API.ai Actions on Google - get current properties like Weather, Location known to Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

When I am using API.ai for Google Actions, is there a way I can access user's current weather or location?

[API.ai](https://api.ai/) does provide some `@sys.*` properties to query user for data, but does API.AI have pre-populated values I can use for response?

[image: API.ai Agent Response]

Developer Reference:
https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/conversation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to request user information, including the user name and the device location. Your action has to ask for permission to request this information from the user using the client library `askForPermission` method. The supported permissions are `NAME`, `DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION` and `DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION`.

If the user accepts your action's request for this information, the requested information can then retrieved by your action fulfillment logic using the client library isPermissionGranted, getUserName and getDeviceLocation methods.

Look at the Name **Psychic sample app** for a complete implementation: [dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-name-psychic-nodejs) .